# Meaning of < in file path in dovecot configuration file?

Tags: configuration, ssl, dovecot

I am updating SSL certificates of Dovecot. One of the configuration lines contains text:

```
#ssl_ca = </path/to/ca
```

What is the meaning of that `<` sign?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Dovecot manual](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/ConfigFile#Reading_value_from_file), the `var_name = </path/to/file` syntax reads the file contents into the variable.